# Elementary Computation of the Flow of the Metric Tensor under Mean Curvature Flow

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, mean-curvature-flows

Context: I have just been introduced to mean curvature and would like to verify an elementary computation to ensure that I am not kidding myself when learning this material.

Let us recall that a smooth family $(M_t)_{t \in I}$ of embedded hypersurfaces flows according to mean curvature if $$\partial_t x = {H}(x),$$ where $x \in M_t$ and $H(x)$ is the mean curvature at $x$.

Let $g_{ij}$ denote the metric tensor of $M_t$. I want to verify that $\partial_t g_{ij} = -2H A_{ij}$.

*Q1:* Is $A_{ij} = -(\partial_i \nu)(\partial_j X)$, where $\nu$ denotes the unit outer normal?

Let us proceed: \begin{eqnarray*}
\partial_tg_{ij} &=& \partial_t( \partial_i X \cdot \partial_j X) \\
&=& \partial_t(\partial_i X) \cdot (\partial_j X) + (\partial_i X) \cdot \partial_t (\partial_j X) \\
& = & \partial_i(\partial_t X) \cdot (\partial_j X) + (\partial_i X) \cdot \partial_j(\partial_t X) \\
&=& \partial_i (H\nu) \cdot (\partial_j X) + (\partial_i X) \cdot \partial_j (H \nu) \\
&=& 2H (\partial_i \nu)(\partial_j X) \\
&=& -2H A_{ij}.  
\end{eqnarray*}

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. Indeed the same is true when the ambient space is not Euclidean. When the immersion is not of coidimension one, we'll have

$$\partial_t g_{ij} = -2 \langle A_{ij}, \vec H\rangle.$$

Comment: Thank you for this.